# How to customize perfect-scrollbar width

Tags: jquery, html, css, perfect-scrollbar

I am using [perfect-scrollbar](https://github.com/noraesae/perfect-scrollbar). The documentation says, that the scrollbar is fully customizable, but there is no such setting like `width`

This is how it looks default: 
[image: default scrollbar width], and it is only 8px width.

But I need at least 12px:
[image: desired scrollbar width[3]]

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the CSS:

[Width](https://github.com/noraesae/perfect-scrollbar/blob/master/src/css/main.scss#L92-L96) and [height](https://github.com/noraesae/perfect-scrollbar/blob/master/src/css/main.scss#L80-L83).

There's no harm in including your own stylesheet, in fact, it's expected.  That way you can style it however you want (not just thickness of the bar, but color and so on).  Just download the unminimized verison from GitHub and include it on your page with any tweaks you want.

Or you can override the values with javascript/jQuery.

Comment: Yes, I have already found that the values in javascript is reading from css

Answer (score 1):

To those using Angular 2+, if you find that you're unable to style the perfect-scrollbar with SCSS, add the prefix `::ng-deep` before your selector. For example, in componentname.component.scss add

```
::ng-deep perfect-scrollbar > div > div.ps__rail-y {
  //styles go here
}
```